# If then clause postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, if-statement, plpgsql

I've defined this function:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('conne1', 'dbname=bdp3e1');
SELECT dblink_connect('conne2', 'dbname=bdp3e2');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertEditorial(nombre VARCHAR(100), CIF INTEGER, ubicacion VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS void AS
$insertEditorial$
BEGIN
    IF ubicacion IS NULL THEN
        dblink_exec('conne2', 'INSERT INTO Editorial VALUES (nombre, CIF);');
    ELSE
        dblink_exec('conne1', 'INSERT INTO Editorial VALUES (nombre, CIF, ubicacion);');
    ENDIF;
END;
$insertEditorial$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when executed, postgreSQL returns the following error:

```
psql:PR3_Procedures.sql:14: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "dblink_exec"
LINE 6:         dblink_exec('conne2', 'INSERT INTO Editorial VALUES ...
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `PERFORM` and change `ENDIF` to `END IF`.

```
...
IF ubicacion IS NULL THEN
    PERFORM dblink_exec('conne2', 'INSERT INTO Editorial VALUES (nombre, CIF);');
ELSE
    PERFORM dblink_exec('conne1', 'INSERT INTO Editorial VALUES (nombre, CIF, ubicacion);');
END IF;
...
```